# Google Maps APIV3 listener set_at not firing until second time

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have the following code, which should trigger an alert when a Polygon shape is changed.  This alert only appears after the shape has been changed twice.  Meaning, I have to resize the shape two times before the event is triggered.

Any idea as to what may be causing this behavior?

```
function drawListener(drawingManager) {
    var coord_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {

        var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray()); //get
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
        var people = [];


        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function () { //check to see if the item has been changed //THIS ONLY GETS CALLED AFTER POLYGON HAS BEEN CHANGED TWICE
            alert('changed');
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer: I must use 'insert_at' in addition to 'set_at'

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function () { 
        alert('changed');
    });

 google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function () {
        alert('also changed');
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: IF you do anything to the path, it will call it fire the event function AGAIN!! The event function is passed (ev, obj). What I do is set obj.updating = true. If I alter path (it's being watched) and it tried to fire the event function AGAIN, If obj.updating, return. At the end of the event function I set obj.updating = false.

Comment: Since I can't edit my comment, another comment to mention that is better to use getPath() rather than path as mentioned by me previously.